# Issue with permission grant to domain users in IBM web sphere queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq, user-permissions

I have domain user called xxx\herath. When I try to add this user in to queue manager's "Manage Authority Record" , It is giving me

Unknown User 'herath@xxx'. (AMQ4808)
  Severity: 10 (Warning)
  Explanation: The named entity for the given type is not defined on the system.
  Response: Make sure the entity is defined and it matches the type of entity.

[image]

This user is not in the websphere mq server machine as a local user. So my question is What is the proper way to grant permission to domain users ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run MQ under a domain id if you want to be able to resolve domain ids. Since Microsoft went to Active Directory, an unknown user (aka local user on a server eg musr_mqadmin) is not able to query the group membership of a domain id.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_domain_user_security
and the infocenter, e.g. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008840_.htm

Comment: That's close but not entirely true. It is possible for a locally defined MUSR_MQADMIN to be granted authority to query domain membership, depending on AD policy such as whether the server itself has a domain trust relationship.  IBM's main interest in directing people to use domain IDs is so the number of configurations they need to support is minimized and tends toward ones that generally can be made to work. This is in general a Good Thing for all concerned but IBM fails to warn strongly against using *the same* acct for multiple QMgrs and that can lead to catastrophic outages. +1 though.