# Can't start a new Queue-Manager on MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

After creating a new Queue-Manager using the MQ Explorer, it's fails to be started properly and provide the following message:

> ---
>
> - Command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\crtmqm" -sa test_qm
>
> ---
>
> WebSphere MQ queue manager created.
>
> Directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\qmgrs\test_qm'
>   created.
>
> The queue manager is associated with installation 'WMQ75Install'.
>
> exitvalue = 2059

I couldn't figure out how to solve it from the logs and tried to start it manually from the MQ Explorer and from the command-line shell as well, but without any success - it just not started.

**HERE IS MY AMQERR01.LOG TEXT:**

21/01/2015 14:18:46 - Process(7960.3) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ6287: WebSphere MQ V7.5.0.2 (p750-002-131001_DE).

EXPLANATION:
WebSphere MQ system information: 
Host Info         :- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 7601: SP1 (MQ
Windows 32-bit) 
Installation      :- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ (WMQ75Install) 
Version           :- 7.5.0.2 (p750-002-131001_DE)
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:46 - Process(7960.3) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5051: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the LOGGER-IO task. This task has
now started 1 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:46 - Process(7960.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5041: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has ended.

EXPLANATION:
The queue manager task LOGGER-IO has ended.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(7528.3) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5051: The queue manager task 'LOGGER-IO' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the LOGGER-IO task. This task has
now started 1 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ7229: 4 log records accessed on queue manager 'test_qm' during the log
replay phase.

EXPLANATION:
4 log records have been accessed so far on queue manager test_qm during the log
replay phase in order to bring the queue manager back to a previously known
state.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ7230: Log replay for queue manager 'test_qm' complete.

EXPLANATION:
The log replay phase of the queue manager restart process has been completed
for queue manager test_qm.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ7231: 0 log records accessed on queue manager 'test_qm' during the recovery
phase.

EXPLANATION:
0 log records have been accessed so far on queue manager test_qm during the
recovery phase of the transactions manager state.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ7232: Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'test_qm'.

EXPLANATION:
The state of transactions at the time the queue manager ended has been
recovered for queue manager test_qm.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ7233: 0 out of 0 in-flight transactions resolved for queue manager
'test_qm'.

EXPLANATION:
0 transactions out of 0 in-flight at the time queue manager test_qm ended have
been resolved.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:49 - Process(7528.4) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5051: The queue manager task 'CHECKPOINT' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the CHECKPOINT task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:51 - Process(9796.3) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'ERROR-LOG' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The restartable utility task manager has started the ERROR-LOG task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:51 - Process(9796.4) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The restartable utility task manager has started the APP-SIGNAL task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:51 - Process(9796.5) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The restartable utility task manager has started the APP-SIGNAL task. This task
has now started 2 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:51 - Process(9796.7) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The restartable utility task manager has started the APP-SIGNAL task. This task
has now started 4 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:51 - Process(9796.6) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5037: The queue manager task 'APP-SIGNAL' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The restartable utility task manager has started the APP-SIGNAL task. This task
has now started 3 times.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:52 - Process(10328.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzfuma.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ8077: Entity 'johnsmith@intranet' has insufficient authority to access object
'test_qm'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: connect/system
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 515 --------------------------------------------------------
21/01/2015 14:18:52 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5525: The WebSphere MQ Object Authority Manager has failed.

EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager has failed to complete an MQ request.
ACTION:
Check the queue manager error logs for messages explaining the failure and try
to correct the problem accordingly. 
----- amqzxma0.c : 3825 -------------------------------------------------------
21/01/2015 14:18:52 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ8003: WebSphere MQ queue manager 'test_qm' started using V7.5.0.2.

EXPLANATION:
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'test_qm' started using V7.5.0.2.
ACTION:

### None.

21/01/2015 14:18:52 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5008: An essential WebSphere MQ process 10328 (amqzfuma.exe) cannot be found
and is assumed to be terminated.

EXPLANATION:
1) A user has inadvertently terminated the process. 2) The system is low on
resources.  Some operating systems terminate processes to free resources.  If
your system is low on resources, it is possible it has terminated the process
so that a new process can be created.
ACTION:
WebSphere MQ will stop all MQ processes.  Inform your systems administrator. 
When the problem is rectified WebSphere MQ can be restarted. 
----- amqzxmb0.c : 9956 -------------------------------------------------------
21/01/2015 14:18:52 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ5050: An essential WebSphere MQ process 9188 (zllPUBSUB) cannot be found and
is assumed to be terminated.

EXPLANATION:
1) A user has inadvertently terminated the process. 2) The system is low on
resources.  Some operating systems terminate processes to free resources.  If
your system is low on resources, it is possible it has terminated the process
so that a new process can be created. 3) MQ has encountered an unexpected
error. Check for possible errors reported in the MQ error logs and for any
FFSTs that have been generated.
ACTION:
WebSphere MQ will attempt to restart the terminated process. 
----- amqzxmb0.c : 9679 -------------------------------------------------------
21/01/2015 14:18:53 - Process(9760.1) User(johnsmith) Program(amqzxma0.exe)
                      Host(NY0035546) Installation(WMQ75Install)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(test_qm)

AMQ8004: WebSphere MQ queue manager 'test_qm' ended.

EXPLANATION:
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'test_qm' ended.
ACTION:

### None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, is johnsmith a domain id? Is this a domain workstation (what is 'johnsmith@intranet')?  My suspicion is you have a machine in a domain but you have not configured MQ to run on a machine in a domain. I think the issue is that at startup MQ is trying to determine what groups the userid 'johnsmith@intranet' is a member of, and hence fails. Its possible, adding johnsmith to the local mqm group *may* get you futher although my suspicion is you need to do the domain configuration. See another answer for details of what to do:
[Issue with permission grant to domain users in IBM web sphere queue manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269631/issue-with-permission-grant-to-domain-users-in-ibm-web-sphere-queue-manager/27279318#27279318)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your UserID is part of the 'mqm' group and second reboot your PC (wonderful things happen when you reboot Windows!).

Comment: The addition of my UserId to the "MQM" users-group is indeed helpfull, but it is better to understand the meaning of configuring the MQ to run on a machine in a domain as @jasonE suggested.

Comment: If your UserID is a local account then follow my comments but if the UserID is in a domain then follow Jason's comments (you may still need to add the domain account to the local 'mqm' group)..